# REPORT/PROGRAM Statement missing, or program type is I(INCLUDE)

Tags: abap

Below is my function module, when I check the below functional module it does not throw any error but when I'm activating it is giving me the following error, which is in image 3.
Someone please help me am I going wrong.

[image: Function Module Source Code Tab]

[image: Function Module Export Tab]

[image: Function Module Import Tab]

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When creating a function group and adding a function module, you will have to activate the function group and the function module once before activating the function module, or at the latest together with the function module. If you don't activate the top include, the leading [`FUNCTION-POOL`](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_751_index_htm/7.51/en-US/abapfunction-pool.htm) statement will be missing, which leads to the error you're seeing.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't activated my functional group. This helped me.

Comment: Can you please tell me, how could you say that functional group is not activated, so that it will be my experience to resolve this error if I overcome this somewhere else.
Thank you

Comment: Simply by having run into this very error myself and helped other people I trained overcome the same error. There are some walls that entry-level ABAP programmers are more likely to run into than others.

Answer (score 1):

This will some kind of problem in the function group (may be another function module in the group has issues). Display the function group (ZSPT_930AM (?)) in SE80, so you have a complete overview and have a look there.